# Two app icons when i install my application from google play

Tags: xamarin.forms, google-play

installing my App on my physical device using the .apk or even by debugging through USB works fine and only makes one launcher icon ,but when i install the same app from google play it makes two launcher icons one with the application name and the other one is called "Pending" and has the same application icon any idea what am i doing worng? , thx in advance
here is my manifest

`AndroidManifest.xaml`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="36" android:versionName="1.0.36" package="com.mypackage.dotforms35" android:installLocation="auto">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<application android:largeHeap="true" android:label="myapplicationame" android:icon="@mipmap/myicon">
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

and here is my main activity

`MainActivity.cs`

```
    [Activity(Label = "myapplicationaname", Icon = "@mipmap/myapplicationicon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = false, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    { 
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {              
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(this);      
            UserDialogs.Init(this);
            IsPlayServicesAvailable();
            CreateNotificationChannel();
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            CachedImageRenderer.Init(true);
            Stormlion.PhotoBrowser.Droid.Platform.Init(this);
         }
```

and here is my `SplashActivity.cs`

```
      [Activity(Label = "myapplicationname", Icon = "@mipmap/myapplicationicon", Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash",LaunchMode =LaunchMode.SingleTop, MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]public class splashactivity : FormsAppCompatActivity
    {  public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);}
            protected override void OnResume()
            {
             base.OnResume();
             Task startupWork = new Task(() => { SimulateStartup(); });
             startupWork.Start();
            }      
        
            async void SimulateStartup()
            {           
            StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Did you ever change `package` value in `AndroidManifest` ? The operation would create two same apps but different names.

Comment: nope i didn't change any package value

Comment: Because we can't reproduce the problem locally,  I think you can go to google play for  
 futher support.

Comment: thanks for your time and answer i will try your suggestion, and my apologies for my late response